# bash write a loop to run a command

Tags: bash

The problem is like this:

There is a script called `run`, I need to change the operation of `run` to make the 2nd field of the output of `run` to be 0 (Please note: it's not the output of `run` but a part of it). I  just don't know how to judge the value of the the 2nd field of the output of `run` for a loop.

Does anyone have any good ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this snippet :

```
out=$(command | awk '{print $2}')
((out)) || echo "zero detected"
```

or simply:

```
command | awk '($2 == 0) {print "zero detected"}'
```

On in a for loop :

```
command | while read a b c d; do
    ((b)) || echo "zero detected"
done
```

note:
`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really need to do some homework on Arithmetic Expressions..

Answer (score 1):

Capture the output of run in an array and modify the second element like this:

```
res=($(echo 1 2 3 4))
# show whole array
echo ${res[@]}
1 2 3 4
# show element 2 with index 1:
echo ${res[1]}
2
# modify second element:
res[1]=0
# verify modified element:
echo ${res[1]}
0
# verify whole thing:
echo ${res[@]}
1 0 3 4
```

so for your command:

```
res=($(run))
res[1]=0
# usage of manipulated result:
echo ${res[@]}
```